# Многоязыковой сайт на PHP с поддержкой шаблонов (%s,%d,%f)

Tags: php, printf, gettext

Как лучше всего реализовать с нуля на PHP многоязычность на сайте для статики с поддержкой шаблонов, то есть.

```
Здравствуйте, %s!
На вашем счету %f гривен.
У вас %d новых сообщений.
```

Первое что приходит на ум - [gettext](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/ref.gettext.php), который используется в большинстве настольных приложений.
Оптимальный ли для этой задачи в PHP использовать `gettext` или есть что-то получше и поудобнее?

Ещё нужна возможность удобно править файл из админки, но желательно без использования БД для хранения, если это возможно.

И подскажите, как в `PHP` в `gettext` работать с шаблонами?
С корректным указанием локали и множественными числами разобрался, но вот как передать нечто:

```
<?=_('Hellow, %s!',$userName)?>
```

ведь `_()` в PHP принимает всего лишь 1 параметр, а аналогичную функцию с поддержкой шаблонов я в PHP не нащёл.

На сколько я понял, это максимум, на что способен [`gettext`](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/ref.gettext.php), а использование шаблонов достигается за счёт аргумента `format` функции [`sprintf`](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php)
Возможно мне и [`gettext`](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/ref.gettext.php) будет не нужен, если получится достаточно легко эмитировать его фишку с окончаниями для множественных чисел.

Comment: Такие вещи вроде не должны быть в админке, перевод сайта - задача его разработчиков, а не пользователей (админы тоже пользователи)

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте посмотрел бы на http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation.html . Возможно, после этого выбор формата отойдет на второй план ;)

Comment: @andreymal, ага ужу иду записываться на курсы арабского. XD

Comment: Эй, профессиональные переводчики тоже могут быть в команде разработчиков

Comment: @andreymal я считаю, что каждый должен заниматься своим делом!
На английский и русский я ещё переведу, но на остальные языки переводить должен заказчик или сам решать эту задачу, удобным для него способом без привлечения меня.

Comment: Ну а я считаю перевод сайта частью его разработки) Хорошо сделанный сайт должен быть пригоден для использования кем угодно без какой-либо дополнительной доработки, а если заказчику приходится самому его переводить перед использованием, то это получается доработка недоделанного сайта. А если заказчик - араб, который перевести ничего не сможет?)

Comment: Впрочем, продолжать наверно нет смысла, у нас просто слишком разные взгляды на жизнь :) Но gettext должен подойти в любом случае (я когда-то делал его редактирование через админку)

Comment: `getText` часто и в пхп фреймоврках используется (например cakephp),  и в ASP.net тоже (OrchardCMS), да и других примеров наверное прилично

Answer (score 0):

Как сделано у меня мультиязычность, может пригодится совет.

Существует директория `templates/main.tpl`
В которой собственно и находится весь дизайн. Файл `main.tpl` отвечает за главный дизайн и всю структуру сайта.

Также существует директория `languages/ru.php` в ней собственно и находятся языковые переменные. А точнее массив!
Выглядит все примерно так:

```
$lang = array (
'name1' =>  'Это мой тайтл',
'name2' =>  'А это футер'
);
```

После чего остается только подключить этот файл в структуру движка

```
require_once '/language/'.$language_user.'.php';
```

И в шаблон добавить в необходимые места данные с перевода в моем случае идет сокращение дабы удобно работать.

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>{lang="name1"}</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
...
</body> 
</html>
```

Теперь если я захочу перевести сайт на еще дополнительно один язык мне надо скопировать исходный перевод и присвоить ему название к примеру `en.php` и перевести весь внутренний текст на английский язык. Думаю это удобно и легко в реализации. Удачу!

Comment: Как таким способом переводить словосочетания вида  «В корзине 4 товара», «У вас 12 непрочитанных сообщений», «Сообщение отправлено 1 неделю назад»?

Comment: Все очень просто. У вас шаблонизатор! Давайте поставим задачу! Необходимо отправить показать сколько у тебя товаров в корзине.
`$lang['name3'] = 'У вас {num} товаров в карзине';`
После чего путем замены вы меняете `{num}` на необходимое число!
`str_replace("{num}", "15", $lang['name3'] );`

Comment: Так получится «У вас 2 товаров в корзине», как же мне получить «У вас 2 товара в корзине»?

Comment: Если стоит задача склонять результат. То тут необходимо добавить специально для склонений. Для даты, для месяцев, для минут минута, что то в этом роде.  
`'dm_lang_board_4' => 'меньше минуты',
'dm_lang_board_5' => '1 минуту назад',
'dm_lang_board_6' => 'минут назад',
'dm_lang_board_7' => 'часов назад',
'dm_lang_board_8' => 'Вчера',
'dm_lang_board_9' => 'Завтра',`

и так далее.  После чего уже делать функцию которая будет склонять и подставлять в окончание нужный текст.

Comment: Что если понадобится переводить сайт на, например, какой-нибудь выдуманный язык, в котором тысяча склонений? Как это дело дружить с английским переводом, в котором два склонения, и русским, в котором три склонения, и при этом обеспечивать возможность переключения между языками? Хочу подробностей в ответе :)

Comment: Что мешает вам перед склонение проверять какой язык подключен!? Английский - склоняй так, русский склоняй иначе! А что касается перевода на какой-нибудь выдуманный язык, то не вижу в этом глобальную проблему!

Comment: Ну, gettext всё равно получается удобнее)

Comment: Каждому свое! =)

Answer (score 0):

Часто в фреймворке есть уже рекомендуемые средства для переводов, вроде
https://symfony.com.ua/doc/current/translation.html

Потом в шаблоне нужно просто писать что-то вроде

```
{{ '<h3>bar</h3>'|trans }}

{% trans %}Hello %name%{% endtrans %}

{% transchoice count %}
    {0} There are no apples|{1} There is one apple|]1,Inf[ There are %count% apples
{% endtranschoice %}

{ message|trans }}

{{ message|transchoice(5) }}

{{ message|trans({'%name%': 'Fabien'}, "app") }}

{{ message|transchoice(5, {'%name%': 'Fabien'}, 'app') }}
```

Answer (score -1):

У вас же шаблоны лежат в определённом каталоге а-ля `templates/templatename.html`. Ну так добавьте в настройки сайта или в конфигурационный файл параметр `language=en` и сделайте структуру каталого `templates/en/templatename.html`. Соответственно для другого языка вы должны все шаблоны перевести. Получится аналог `gettext`.
А уж как в шаблоне выводить значения - проблема шаблонизатора, а не мультиязычности.

ИМХО иметь в шаблоне  позиционные плейсхолдеры - зло. У вас поменялся порядок аргументов по какой-то причине - шаблон сломался.

Comment: Смешивать шаблоны и мультиязычность - плохая идея: переводчики не обязаны разбираться в шаблонизации.